# Describing the common cold or flu in Spanish

Tags: uso-de-palabras, selección-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, vocabulario-médico

In English, when talking about common viruses people get, there are generally two categories:

- a **[cold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_cold)** is generally mild and can come with runny nose, sneezing, coughing, sore throat etc.
- a **[flu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flu)** is generally more severe and can bring fever, chills, fatigue etc.

In my experience, in Spanish both of these tend to be wrapped up in one word: *gripe*.

What are the official and informal ways of referring to these diseases? 
What regional variants exists?

Comment: Even in English, I can't remember the last time an Australian complained of having a more *cold*! (-:

Comment: I am told that in Ecuador, its like Chile mentioned above.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At least in Mexico which is where I come from:

As you say *gripe* or *gripa* are used to refer to both the common cold and the flu. This is the colloquial way of saying it.

It would be more correct to refer to the common cold as

> resfriado / catarro

and to the flu as

> gripe / gripa / influenza

but it is not that common, like I said, where I come from.

Comment: In Spain, to have a cold is "tener catarro" or "estar constipado" (not to be confused with "constipated", which in Spain is "estreñido"), "resfriado" is more "formal". Flu is just "gripe", not gripa nor influenza. So, in Spain we make the difference between cold and flu.

Answer (score 5):

Here in Chile, we say:

- *Resfrío* (common) or *Resfriado* (less common): cold
- *Gripe* (common) or *Influenza* (less common, because *gripe* and *influenza* are actually different): flu

Answer (score 4):

In Dominican Republic, we differentiate between having a cold (tener catarro) and the flu (gripe). Influenza is use more in reference to a pandemic type of flu.

Answer (score 3):

Well... I'm from Mexico but where I come frome we just say "gripa" for cold and "gripa" for flu [haha] but we say that it was a very bad "gripa" or "gripa de perro" (dog's flu) very commonly used. There are other words but those are used in the TV or other countries.

Answer (score 2):

#### Cold

- catarro, constipado, romadizo, coriza, pasmo, fluxión, [decenso](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BvmtKj3) <sup>0</sup>
- enfriamiento, resfriamiento, resfriado, resfrío, resfrío común

#### Flu

- gripe, [gripa](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=gripa),<sup>1</sup> gripola <sup>4</sup>
- influenza, resfriado, trancazo,<sup>2</sup> [monga](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Pe1mfQG) <sup>3</sup>

---

<sup>0. Desusado</sup>
 <sup>1. México, Paraguay, Colombia, Ecuador</sup>
 <sup>2. Coloq.</sup>
 <sup>3. Puerto Rico</sup>
 <sup>4. El Salvador</sup>

Answer (score 1):

[**Trancazo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=aHHudUc) is another term for "gripe"

> 2. m. coloq. gripe.

and it is often used (informally) in Spain ("¡Tengo un trancazo!").